# run vbscript mhta

Tags: vbscript

i want to run vbscript from mhta

Comment: man can you delete tread i want rewirt

Answer (score 3):

```
mshta "vbscript:window.close(msgbox("test"))"
```

`WScript` or `CScript` script hosts are not able to run a script if it is not stored in a file. But you can use `mshta` and the `vbscript:` protocol to run simple commands.

Anyway, for this case, it is easier to use

```
msg console "test"
```

**edited** to adapt to comments

i've being testing. vbscript parser in the mshta url has to face a lot of limitations. And problems with spaces, concatenation of commands with `:`, problems with procedure calling as a function but you can not use `call` keyword as a space is required, ....

The only stable, "easy" way of doing it is to prepare the vbscript to execute as a string, with no spaces inside it, and use the execute method to run it

```
mshta "vbscript:window.close(execute("msgbox"&chr(32)&"""test"":msgbox"&chr(32)&"""this"&chr(32)&"should"&chr(32)&"work"""))"
mshta "vbscript:window.close(execute("server=CreateObject(""WScript.Shell"").RegRead(""HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Volatile"&chr(32)&"Environment\LOGONSERVER""):For"&chr(32)&"i=1"&chr(32)&"to"&chr(32)&"3:msgbox"&chr(32)&"i"&chr(38)&"server:next"))"
```

Comment: thanx you so much
can you delete this tread plzz

Comment: @user3854831, Why does it need to be deleted? As i see it, the main reason for SO is to help others. Maybe someone find this useful or can be improved by someone. If not, the whole question will be ignored. But it is a community decission.

Comment: Plz man can you delete just the update
this is for security reasons